# Get last state even after refresh ReactJS with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I get the last state even after refreshing the page? State goes back to 0 after refresh

```
const [updateCounter, setUpdateCounter] = useState(0);

async function updateCounter() { 
  setUpdateCounter(updateCounter + 1);
}

<Button onClick={updateCounter()}>Update</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When `updateCounter` changes, put it into local storage:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(Number(localStorage.counter) || 0);
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.counter = counter;
}, [counter]);
```

You also should not have both a `updateCounter` number (in state) and a `updateCounter` function - use different names.